# Why this giving me 0?

Tags: java

In the below program

```
package test;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //System.out.println(2+3*4);
        int temp=0;
        temp+=temp++;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

}
```

I do not understand why its giving me 0.Can any body please explain it?

Comment: What does `++` do and what does `+=` do?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis arent both same,I++ isnt equals to I=I+1;

Comment: They are absolutely not both the same. You need to go through [Java's operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) once more.

Comment: you mark duplicate more than answering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post increment ++ operator increment the value after the expression.

In the code

`temp += temp++;` so the expression will be evaluated as

i.e. `temp= temp + temp++;`

```
temp = 0 + 0 (value will not increment here as you are using post increment)

temp = 0
```

Lets take one more example

`temp= temp++ + temp;` so it will be evaluated as

```
temp = 0 + 1 (value is incremented here mean after temp++ expression)
```

then print the value it will show `1`.

Comment: Isnt temp+=temp++; similar to temp=temp+temp++ so temp++ will be 1 and now temp=temp+1 that is temp=0+1; so temp will be 1

Comment: no dear post increment the value after the expression. Do one thing replace temp++ -> ++temp you will find the answer

Comment: -1 for the comment "value will not increment as you are using post" for explanation check my answer.

Comment: @RaviKumar the explanation is for temp++ mean there the value will not be incement,it will be incremented after the expression.Also updated answer i thnk it will help u

Answer (score 1):

Because if you use variable++ in an expression, the variable will increment after the expression is calculated. If you write:

```
++variable
```

The variable will be incremented and then the expression will be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value on the postincrement operator,it will increment the value after the temp is assigned.

Preincrement would be better

```
++temp
```

Comment: Better than what? At doing what? At not getting 0?

Answer (score 0):

`++` post increment operation done later, `0+0 = 0` is assigned first to temp and

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand ,can you please be bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

```
temp+=temp++;
--> temp=temp+ temp++ ;
-> temp = 0 + 0 (and now increment temp i.e, after assigning)
-->so, temp = 0
```

Comment: where is increment performed?

Comment: after value of temp and temp++(without incrementing) is assigned to temp. temp++ is performed but is not assigned to the original temp.

Comment: why not assigned to original temp?

Comment: The variables will not be the same on stack. So cannot be assigned directly back.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time to find the answer and here what i got

int temp = 0;

temp+=temp++;

ie temp = temp + temp++;

now what happens here step by stem

1 step temp = exp(0 + 0)

2 step temp value will be incremented to 1

3 step temp will be assigned the value 0 from expression 1

so actually in the expression temp value is incremented but again reset to 0 due to assignment operator

here is my code as a proof

```
int i=0,j=0;
System.out.println(i+=i++);
System.out.println(j+=j++);
System.out.println("i= "+i+", j="+j);
System.out.println(i=i+i++);
System.out.println(j=i+j++);
System.out.println("i= "+i+", j="+j);
j+=i++;
System.out.println("i= "+i+", j="+j);
```

output is

```
0
0
i= 0, j=0
0
0
i= 0, j=0
i= 1, j=0
```

so you can see in the last line value of i is 1 that is it got incremented and the value of j is 0 due to assignment operator

and yes you should use pre increment to make it work as you expected this is just to show why this unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

```
temp+=temp++   
temp=temp+temp++;
```

both the above statement are equivalent.As postfix operator will increment its value after once used.So its 0, and 0+0 makes 0.